# Logarithms equation with tricky transformations

Tags: logarithms

$$8^{x-2}\times5^{x+2}=1$$

This one according to wolfram alpha it has nice solution $$x = \frac{2 (\log(8)-\log(5))}{\log(8)+\log(5)}$$

I see one could guess this solution and just assume left side is increasing function and be done, but I want to see some transformations which could bring me to this solution and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

$$
8^{x-2}\times5^{x+2}= 8^{-2} \cdot 5^2 \cdot 8^x\cdot 5^x = \frac{5^2}{8^2} \cdot 40^x.
$$
That is equal to $1$ precisely if
$$
40^x = \frac{64}{25}
$$
and that holds only if
$$
x = \log_{40}\frac{64}{25}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\log(a^n.b^m)=n\log a+m\log b$$
take the $\log$
$$(x-2)\log 8+(x+2)\log 5=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
a^nb^n = (ab)^n\\
a^{n+m} = a^na^m\\
\log(1) = 0
$$
can you use these rules to determine the value of $x$?